# How to find out when this expression is greater than 0

Tags: inequality

For what value of $a$ is this expression always greater than zero?

$$ax_2^2+10x_1^2+2x_2x_1+6x_3x_1+x_3^2+2x_2x_3$$

I know that the answer is 5 but I have no idea of how to calculate that by hand. How do one even solve such a problem by hand?

Comment: This is a quadratic form... you hace to study wether it is positive definite

Comment: Setting the discriminant $\le 0$ may help

Comment: @TitoEliatron Please tell me more. How do I do that?

Comment: Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix)

Comment: @TitoEliatron okay thx for the link, I have to look deeper into that, I have never seen that before

Answer (score 2):

No value of $a$ guarantees that the expression is always greater than zero, since $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ will yield the value zero, regardless of the value of $a$. If you meant greater or equal than zero, the associated symmetric matrix can be either positive definite or positive semi-definite.

$$
ax_2^2+10x_1^2+2x_2x_1+6x_3x_1+x_3^2+2x_2x_3= x^T \begin{pmatrix}10 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & a & 1\\3 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}x.
$$

If you study this matrix (using the determinants of the principal minors or the eigenvalues) you'll see that:

1. If $a < 5$ the matrix is either indefinite or negative definite and so it does not meet the requirements.
2. If $a > 5$, the matrix is positive definite and so the expression takes positive values for non-zero vectors (and zero for the zero vector).
3. If $a=5$ the matrix is positive semi-definite. The expression takes the value zero for eigenvectors associated with $\lambda = 0$ and positive values for all other vectors.

The final answer should be $a \ge 5$.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. How did you come up with that matrix, where did the 3s come from?

Comment: @J.Doe Compute the product and you'll see...  For instance $3 = \frac 62$ the coefficient 6 of the term $x_3 x_1$ is split between the terms $x_1 x_3$ and $x_3 x_1$ that turn up in the product.

Comment: @PierreCarre  $a x_2^2$, right?

Comment: @RiverLi you are right! I misread it... I'll make the necessary changes.

Comment: @PierreCarre It is nice. (+1)